# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: scala, spark-graphx

I am trying to access spark GRAPHX . 
i have tried following code :

```
/**
  * Created by xyz on 5/7/16.
  */

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.graphx._



object simple {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {


    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("untitled1")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, "graphx/data/followers.txt", true).partitionBy(PartitionStrategy.RandomVertexCut)
    val triCounts = graph.triangleCount().vertices
    val users = sc.textFile("graphx/data/users.txt").map { line =>
      val fields = line.split(",")
      (fields(0).toLong, fields(1))
    }
    val triCountByUsername = users.join(triCounts).map { case (id, (username, tc)) =>
      (username, tc)
    }
    println(triCountByUsername.collect().mkString("\n"))
  }
}
```

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("untitled1")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

```
val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, "graphx/data/followers.txt", true).partitionBy(PartitionStrategy.RandomVertexCut)
val triCounts = graph.triangleCount().vertices
val users = sc.textFile("graphx/data/users.txt").map { line =>
  val fields = line.split(",")
  (fields(0).toLong, fields(1))
}
val triCountByUsername = users.join(triCounts).map { case (id, (username, tc)) =>
  (username, tc)
}
println(triCountByUsername.collect().mkString("\n"))
```

========================================

but its giving me following error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
>       at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:52)
>       at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$.log(GraphLoader.scala:26)
>       at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:59)
>       at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$.logInfo(GraphLoader.scala:26)
>       at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$.edgeListFile(GraphLoader.scala:84)
>       at simple$.main(simple.scala:18)
>       at simple.main(simple.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

I have a data file having following content :

> 2 1
>   4 1
>   1 2
>   6 3
>   7 3
>   7 6
>   6 7
>   3 7

Comment: Check your dependencies : your app assembly requires a method which is not provided by the version of the class inside the Spark env where you submit

Comment: @avy, did u find any solution, I am facing the same issue